# Chrome App: How to enumerate files under a static folder?

Tags: google-chrome-app

How can I enumerate files under a static folder (such as images where all the static images used by my app are stored) while developing a chrome app?

What I have tried:
- looked at these links [1](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index), [2](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_other). i am not trying to read from local or user storage. i want to read from static storage. static storage are the folders where an app stores its static contents - assets like images, css, js etc.
- looked at [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) link. but my app needs to be able to enumerate all files under a static folder without prompting the user for any action/permission.

i will give an example of why this is useful. imagine i want to release an app using which users can read my poems. i want a static folder where i save poems i write. then as i write new poems, these poems should then be made available automatically without having to do any code changes. further i was able to do this on android without any user prompt whatsoever so expect chrome platform should also support this - there cannot be any security excuses.

Comment: There is a different answer if you want to enumerate files INSIDE the app folder, not just any folder on the machine. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes, i want to enumerate files under a static folder e.g., a folder called images where i store all the images used by my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to enumerate **app's own files**, it's possible via [`chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry).

It returns a `DirectoryEntry` for the root of your app that you can navigate and iterate through.

See this question: [How do I get a list of filenames in a subfolder of a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720903/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-filenames-in-a-subfolder-of-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: thanks. i think this is what i was looking for. i'll try it and let you know.

Comment: have been trying to test your solution (i think it will work) but can't get chrome app to run. it just displays blank screen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771358/chrome-app-displays-blank-window-and-wont-do-anything/2477147

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The user will have to choose some parent folder with chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry at some point. However, you can arrange things so this is done only once when the app is first installed, and then save the FileEntry using the retained-entry API.