# How do I get a list of filenames in a subfolder of a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was wondering if it is possible to get a list of filenames of all files in a subfolder of a Chrome extension.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry) method to get a `DirectoryEntry` for the Chrome extension, then use the [FileSystem API](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-dir-sys.html) to query its contents

```js
chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function(directoryEntry) {
    var directoryReader = directoryEntry.createReader();
    // List of DirectoryEntry and/or FileEntry objects.
    var filenames = [];
    (function readNext() {
        directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
            if (entries.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
                    filenames.push(entries[i].name);
                }
                readNext();
            } else {
                // No more entries, so all files in the directory are known.
                // Do something, e.g. print all file names:
                console.log(filenames);
            }
        });
    })();
});
```

This is a basic example that lists the names of all files *and* directories of the root in your Chrome extension package. If you want to query the contents of a specific directory, then you need to get that entry first. E.g. to list the contents of the `_locales` directory. Second parameter should be the Object instance:

```js
directoryEntry.getDirectory('_locales', {}, function(subDirectoryEntry) {
    var directoryReader = subDirectoryEntry.createReader();
    // etc.. same code as in previous snippet.
});
```