# How to access a specific folder to get file names within my extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, directory

So i need to get names of files in my "db" folder, that i later need to use in my extension. I searched on how to do this and I can get all file names from my root extension folder but not from any other.

This is the code that gives back all file names from extension folder that i found from this question: [How do I get a list of filenames in a subfolder of a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720903/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-filenames-in-a-subfolder-of-a-chrome-extension)

```
chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function(directoryEntry) {
var directoryReader = directoryEntry.createReader();
// List of DirectoryEntry and/or FileEntry objects.
var filenames = [];
(function readNext() {
    directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
        if (entries.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
                filenames.push(entries[i].name);
            }
            readNext();
        } else {
            // No more entries, so all files in the directory are known.
            // Do something, e.g. print all file names:
            console.log(filenames);
        }
    });
})();
});
```

This is the code that is supposed to do what i want but i cant figure out how to implement it here

```
directoryEntry.getDirectory('_locales', {}, function(subDirectoryEntry) {
var directoryReader = subDirectoryEntry.createReader();
// etc.. same code as in previous snippet.
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your ***manifest.json*** and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: Look at the second code snippet: the hint is that it starts with the same line as in the first one which indicates the point at which you need to insert the code from the first one into the second one. Found an example: [Add SVG in Angular2 all at once](//stackoverflow.com/a/42550981)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I needed was this.

```
chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function(directoryEntry) {
    directoryEntry.getDirectory('index', {}, function(subDirectoryEntry) {
        var directoryReader = subDirectoryEntry.createReader();
        // List of DirectoryEntry and/or FileEntry objects.
        var filenames = [];
        (function readNext() {
            directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                if (entries.length) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
                        filenames.push(entries[i].name);
                    }
                    readNext();
                } else {
                    // No more entries, so all files in the directory are known.
                    // Do something, e.g. print all file names:
                    console.log(filenames);
                }
            });
        })();
    });
});
```