# chrome.fileSystem reading and writing a directory

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, file-access

Is it possible to access a fixed directory from the Chrome App (lets say "/assets") and read all files from it and also add new files without prompting the user?

The API doesn't help much.

Comment: This? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718047/chrome-app-how-to-enumerate-files-under-a-static-folder

Answer (score 0):

That depends on where the directory is. If it is in the application package, you will be able to read the files but not create new ones. See https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry.

If it is in the app's sandboxed file system (i.e. invisible to other applications), you will be able to read and create new files and directories. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/.

If it is an external directory (e.g. on Windows C:/assets) then no, this isn't possible by design. Apps are designed to be sandboxed, with any access to files outside their sandbox at the user's discretion.

Comment: Is file creation really supported inside the application package?
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713854/chrome-app-securityerror-on-file-creation

Comment: Sorry I just realized your point - your question specifically mentioned creation. I'll update the answer.