# Chrome App SecurityError on file creation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I have the following code:

```
chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function(directoryEntry) 
{
    directoryEntry.getFile("files/test.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) 
    {
        console.log(fileEntry);
    },
    function(error)
    {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

If the file does not exist and create is true I get an `It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources.` error. But if it does exist and create is false I get access to the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I know one reason may cause the SecurityError. Chrome cannot be in Incognito Mode. Did you use that mode?

Comment: I run this as a Chrome App, not in the browser.

Comment: Well I see. It seems it is the same issue with this one: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/j4f48wn-pBE